# How to populate Wordpress Posts using wp_insert_post and SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I am working on a project where I would like to programmatically create wordpress posts using an SQL query from an external database.  I have been able to populate HighCharts graphs and display data in a tabular format querying the SQL databases with PHP.  However, I can not figure out how to use wp_insert_post in the same way. I am also unsure where I should put this code.  Any help is much appreciated! Here is my PHP.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Post Creator

 * Description: Matt's Post Creator
 * Version: 0.2
 * Author: Matt 
 * Author URI:
 * License: GPLv2
 */

/**
 * Enable PHP in Widgets
 */

$conzz = mysql_connect("localhost","database","databasepassword");





if (!$conzz) {


  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());


}





mysql_select_db("chiensi_testing", $conzz);




$resultzz = mysql_query("SELECT T1.ID, REBATE_CODE, LONG_DESC, INCENT_TECH_ID, UPGRADE_TECH FROM T_L_INCENTIVES T1 INNER JOIN T_L_INCENT_TECH T2 ON T1.L_INCENT_TECH = T2.ID INNER JOIN T_LIGHTING_TYPE T3 ON T2.E_LIGHTING_TYPE_ID = T3.ID");



while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultzz)) {


  global $user_ID;
$new_post = array(
'post_title' =>  $row['REBATE_CODE'] ,
'post_content' =>  $row['LONG_DESC'] ,
'post_status' => 'publish',
'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
'post_author' => $user_ID,
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_category' => array(10)
);
$posts_array[]=$new_post;

}

mysqli_close($conzz);

foreach ( $posts_array as $post ) {

$post_id = wp_insert_post($post);
};


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED AFTER COMMENTS BELOW:

Try killing your connection to the first database before attempting to call wp_insert_post

```
$conzz = mysql_connect("localhost","database","databasepassword");
 if (!$conzz) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());


}
mysql_select_db("database_name", $conzz);

 $resultzz = mysql_query("SELECT T1.ID, REBATE_CODE, LONG_DESC, INCENT_TECH_ID, UPGRADE_TECH FROM T_L_INCENTIVES T1 INNER JOIN T_L_INCENT_TECH T2 ON T1.L_INCENT_TECH = T2.ID INNER JOIN T_LIGHTING_TYPE T3 ON T2.E_LIGHTING_TYPE_ID = T3.ID");

$posts_array = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultzz)) {


  global $user_ID;
$new_post = array(
'post_title' =>  $row['REBATE_CODE'] ,
'post_content' =>  $row['LONG_DESC'] ,
'post_status' => 'publish',
'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
'post_author' => $user_ID,
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_category' => array(10)
);
$posts_array[]=$new_post;

}

mysqli_close($conzz);

foreach ( $posts_array as $post ) {

$post_id = wp_insert_post($post);
};



?>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help!  The reason I am setting up the connection to the database is because it is an external database that is separate from the Wordpress Database.  I need to pull values from this separate database and create WP posts with the results.

Comment: Then you would need to use the the sql connection as you have shown, store the returned values as an array, and then call wp_insert_post using those returned values as parameters

Comment: @Matt Shirk Are you getting any errors back from your code?

Comment: Hi - I am not receiving any errors now, but no posts are created either.  I tried adding my code as a plugin, but when I try to "activate" it, nothing happens.  I tried adding my code to "functions.php", but then I was kicked out of the Admin Dashboard and was unable to log back in until I removed the code from "functions.php" manually.  I think that the problem may lie with adding the array items to the wp_insert_post function.  Am I doing this correctly?  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Can you check the array that your building in the while loop? Instead of calling wp_insert_post `var_dump( $new_post);` Also, you shouldn't be getting locked out of admin for adding this to your functions.php, whatevers causing that could be the source of all your troubles.  Is it the white screen of death?

Comment: Hello, yes after enabling "Debug" mode in wp_config.php, I can now see PHP/Wordpress errors.  The error that I receive is this:


        Wordpress Database Error: Table  'database_name.wp_phppc_functions' doesn't exist] SELECT * FROM `wp_phppc_functions` WHERE `id` = 31

I only receive this error when I add the "wp_insert_post" or "var_dump functions".  Otherwise the array returns correctly. I have no idea what "wp_phppc_functions" does or where it is located.  I am able to pull the data and populate it in an HTML table, but I am not able to create new posts.

Comment: Try addding `global $wpdb;` at the start of your script?

Comment: Hi, I have tried all of these and still receive the same error

Comment: Sounds like wp_insert_post is getting the database name wrong, have you tried killing the connection to the first database before calling wp_insert_post()?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help.  I have put my code into a plugin file, here is my code so far

Comment: Hey, can't see your code, but edited my answer to kill the first connection.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help.  I have tried using your latest code but I still get the error

       ' Wordpress Database Error: [Table database_name.wp_phppc_functions doesn't exist]<br>
   <code>SELECT * FROM wp_phppc_functions WHERE id = 31'

I have updated my code above with the latest iteration, any further insight you can give me would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your help.
You were correct about the "PHP Code for Posts" plugin causing a problem.  I removed it and the code you provided worked nicely.

Comment: Awesome!  Glad you got it sorted :)